# Script to gather all the files ending in .log and create a tar.gz file

Tags: unix, log-files, scripting

I'm currently using this script line to find all the log files from a given directory structure and copy them to another directy where I can easily compress them.

```
find . -name "*.log" -exec cp \{\} /tmp/allLogs/ \;
```

The problem I have, is, the directory/subdirectory information gets lost because, I'm copying only the file.

For instance I have:

```
./product/install/install.log
./product/execution/daily.log
./other/conf/blah.log
```

And I end up with:

```
/tmp/allLogs/install.log
/tmp/allLogs/daily.log
/tmp/allLogs/blah.log
```

And I would like to have:

```
/tmp/allLogs/product/install/install.log
/tmp/allLogs/product/execution/daily.log
/tmp/allLogs/other/conf/blah.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the reason to copy them to another directory to compress them? The following will create a compressed tar file off all the log files while keeping the directory structure in one step (Assuming it is run from the root directory:

```
find . -iname '*.log' -print0 | xargs -0 tar zcf /tmp/test.tar.gz
```

For example:

```
kbrandt@alpine:~/scrap/tar$ find . *.log
.
./foo
./bar
./bar/baz.log
kbrandt@alpine:~/scrap/tar$ find . -iname '*.log' -print0 | xargs -0 tar zcf /tmp/test.tar.gz
#List files in the archive with the -t switch
kbrandt@alpine:~/scrap/tar$ tar -tzf /tmp/test.tar.gz 
./bar/baz.log
```

Comment: The reason is ... ignorance, definitely :) .) Thank you Kyle

Answer (score 2):

Try using [cpio](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cpio) in pass-through mode

`find . -name '*.log' | cpio -pdm /tmp/allLogs`

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name "*.log" | tar -cz --files-from - -f /path/to/file.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

What about filtering just the logs into the archive:

```
sudo tar -zcvf archive.tar.gz /path/**/*.log
```